# Bus services between SNCF gare d'Andorre-L'Hospitalet and Pas de la Casa

Tags: trains, buses, sncf, andorra

I've seen on the SNCF website for gare d'Andorre-L'Hospitalet that some buses run from the station to Pas de la Casa - https://www.ter.sncf.com/occitanie/gares/87611517/Andorre-LHospitalet/pratique

"SNCF and HISPANO-ANDORRANA service - Pas de la Casa / Andorra la Vielle - Departure location from station yard - Service range 7:35 am - 7:45 pm" - via Google Translate

However, there seems to be very limited and conflicting situation about theses buses and there prices (or even if they still exist).

The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gare_d'Andorre-L'Hospitalet) page for the station indicates that the just one bus runs out from the station at 0935 run by SNCF, with no information on the return journey, as well as buses by [http://www.andorrabus.com/](http://www.andorrabus.com/index.php?accion=inici&idmenu=1&cap=1) (see below).

Various older posts/webpages point to a bus run by [http://www.andorrabus.com/](http://www.andorrabus.com/index.php?accion=inici&idmenu=1&cap=1) - but the ever helpful [man in seat 61](https://www.seat61.com/Andorra.htm) advises that these buses were suspended in early 2019.

[Another page](https://www.petitfute.co.uk/v53284-andorra-la-vella/c1122-voyage-transports/c1145-avion-bateau-bus-train-taxi-parking/c1153-bus-autocar/290432-hispano-andorrana.html) claims buses leave the railway station at 0850 and 1955 -  with the buses continuing to Andorra la Vella bus station - presumably passing through Pas de la Casa. But with no date or source.

Are any buses still scheduled to run on this route? And if so, what times do they run? I'm referring to a normal timetable, not any special coronavirus changes- clearly not going to be doing any traveling in the short term.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line is currently out of service, but in winter there is a shuttle service operated separately for ski-pass holders (tickets included).

https://visitandorra.com/en/visitor-information/how-do-i-get-to-andorra/get-to-by-train/andorra-l-hospitalet-station/:

> You can reach Andorra from station on a Grup Montmantell coach. **(This line is currently out of service)**
>
> During the winter ski season, there is a shuttle service between
>   L’Hospitalet and Pas de la Casa for skiers.
>
> There is also a taxi service between L’Hospitalet and Andorra: Taxi
>   l’Hospitalet (+33) 0561 644 714; Taxi Pas de la Casa (+376) 856 255.

This is also confirmed by an email response in a [TripAdvisor thread](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g190391-i1957-k12706912-Bus_from_L_Hospitalet_pres_l_Andorre_discontinued-Andorra.html):

> Good afternoon,
>
> I am afraid the bus from Hospitalet-près-l’Andorre to Andorra is not
>   available anymore. The company cancelled it and it hasn’t been
>   re-taken so far.
>
> When arriving at the train station in Hospitalet, you have the option
>   to call a taxi to go to Pas de la Casa, and then, from there, you can
>   take a bus to Andorra la Vella.
>
> Taxis prices are approximately 30 euros. The bus from Pas de la Casa
>   to Andorra la Vella is a 6,80 euros ticket.
>
> Here are the phone numbers of the taxis’ companies:
>
> Taxis Pas de la Casa: Taxi Altitud Pas (TAP) (00376) 856 255.
>
> Taxis Hospitalet: (0033) 5 61 64 47 14.